# Not able to find the elements in the window using applescript

Tags: applescript

am new to applescript. I want to access elements inside a dialog box/window. I tried following code.

```
tell application "System Events"
set procs to processes
set windowName to {}
repeat with proc in procs
    try
          if exists (window 1 of proc) then
        repeat with w in windows of proc
            if w's name contains "App Name" then
                copy w's name to the end of windowName
                copy properties of w to the end of windowName
            end if
        end repeat
             end if
    end try -- ignore errors
end repeat
end tell
return windowName
```

But am only able to get the 4 elements from window:
1.Close
2.Minimize
3.Maximize
4.window title

Nothing from inside the window/dilog.

Can any one help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0):

You are only asking the window for its name and properties. If you want its elements then ask for its "ui elements".

Comment: Tried UI elements also, it also returns the same 4 elements.